# radio button using bootstrap in firefox is blurry

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

I am using boostrap to display some radio buttons.  In Chrome and Edge, the buttons look crisp, but in Firefox (52.0.2 32-bit) the buttons are very blurry.

Sample html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="radio-button"><input class="form-control" name="radioName" type="radio" value="1"> Yes</label>
      <label class="radio-button"><input class="form-control" name="radioName" type="radio" value="0"> No</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Sample css:

```
label.radio-button {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

label.radio-button input[type=radio] {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7zsp1oao/2/)

Here are sample images:

Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Edge
[image: Edge]

Firefox
[image: Firefox]

Comment: I am using the same version of firefox with 64-bit and it renders properly [here](http://imgur.com/a/Usbpr).

Comment: I might need to just uninstall / reinstall firefox.  I'll try that later today.

Comment: I uninstalled / reinstalled the 32 bit version.  That didn't change anything.  I downloaded the 64-bit version and that didn't change anything either.  This might not really be a programming question since others can't duplicate it.

Comment: Yes. Strange though .

Comment: I have this problem too. Very similar. In my case the radio buttons are too small in the context, so I am using transform: scale(2). That causes in Firefox only the issue as shown by the OP. I did a lot of searching about this, and very many solutions are offered using different styles. Nothing has worked.